Pyre-check error for @property: Undefined attribute: `<class>` has no attribute `<attribute>`
I use pyre-check for type checking my python code, with strict setting on. It works fine except for OOP properties.
Example code:
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, full_name: str):
        self.full_name = full_name

    @property
    def full_name(self) -> str:
        return self._full_name

    @full_name.setter
    def full_name(self, value: str) -> None:
        self._full_name = value

# Usage
obj = MyClass("John Doe")
print(obj.full_name)

Undefined attribute: `<class>` has no attribute `_full_name`.

I believe its because _full_name is not defined in the init. But if I use the following code, then the setter is not used.
 self._full_name = full_name

I want to only expose full_name via the getter and setter. I believe Pyre incorrectly says this is wrong, or how else should I make my code?

There is no point in having a property that only ever delegates the operations to the actual attribute. If this is just a contrived example and does not reflect your actual code, please [edit] to improve that.

That does not change the question. Whether its just a simple code example or if there is logic applied, the error remains the same.

I want to use Property, your comment of not using property does not at all answer the question. If I do have some logic in my setter or getter the problem remains.

Does self.full_name = self._full_name = full_name) work for you, then?

Erm, that's not very useful behaviour by pyre. Neither mypy nor pyright complains about your code snippet. But then again, pyre was guided in design by facebook/meta's own code, and they probably have a standards or style guide that doesn't accept the snippet you have here, otherwise they would have fixed this.

This has nothing to do with properties... You're missing the _full_name attribute annotation, the error is emitted for the property body, not on the call site. Just add _full_name: str annotation to the class itself. pyre only supports attributes annotated in the class body or added in __init__, neither of which is present in your case. A conformant checker is allowed to do so, so no pyre bug here either. That produces another diagnostic which is just a pyre quirk - you either want to disable that or provide a redundant initial value.

@STerliakov pyre complains if an annotated attribute isn't explicitly initialised in __init__, which means merely adding _full_name: str to the class body (and not assigning a value in __init__) will also show an error. This is why I don't think it's a useful behaviour, but YMMV.

@dROOOze Yep, that's what I meant by "a pyre quirk":)
